# I have some "expired" mead yeast, is it still good?

Tags: yeast, mead

I have some liquid mead yeast that has expired a couple years ago, according to the date on it. It has always been kept in the refrigerator. Could it be revived and used or do I need to buy some new yeast?

Comment: It would certainly be easier/faster to just buy new yeast.

Answer (score 11):

A couple years is a LONG time :)  I would make a starter with the yeast, if the starter takes off then you're all set. If it doesn't get going, get some new yeast.

These are some good instructions for making a starter

http://www.beerdude.com/yeast_starter.shtml

Answer (score 3):

I haven't brewed mead, but having brewed regularly for a couple of years I would suggest not using it. Liquid yeast (for beer) costs about $10 where I am, and I wouldn't risk wrecking a batch because of some old yeast.

Comment: +1 For starting fresh. New yeast is an insignificant cost compared to the investment of money and time for an entire batch.